# Django Allauth and urls

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have a dev environment for a test of Django.  I am running Python 3.5.2 out of a "local" `pyenv` install.  I have Django 1.10.2.  I discovered the `allauth` registration plugin yesterday and have been playing with it but have hit a snag.

My site is "dev.my.domain.com".  The intent is that there will not be any "public" information on the production version of this site.  The production version will be called something like: "members.my.domain.com".  So, I wonder if it is possible for the "allauth" plugin to have all non-/adomn inbound requests check for auth?

So, requests to:

- dev.my.domain.com
- dev.my.domain.com/foo
- dev.my.domain.com/foo/../bar/...

should all be checked for auth.  If not there then I assume "allauth" will redirect to a login/signup page.

I have tried setting the `Members/urls.py` file as:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

but that bombs with a Page Not Found error and the `DEBUG` message:

```
    Using the URLconf defined in Members.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^$ ^ ^signup/$ [name='account_signup']
    ^$ ^ ^login/$ [name='account_login']
    ^$ ^ ^logout/$ [name='account_logout']
    ^$ ^ ^password/change/$ [name='account_change_password']
    ^$ ^ ^password/set/$ [name='account_set_password']
    ^$ ^ ^inactive/$ [name='account_inactive']
    ^$ ^ ^email/$ [name='account_email']
    ^$ ^ ^confirm-email/$ [name='account_email_verification_sent']
    ^$ ^ ^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
    ^$ ^ ^password/reset/$ [name='account_reset_password']
    ^$ ^ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_done']
    ^$ ^ ^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
    ^$ ^ ^password/reset/key/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
    ^$ ^social/
    ^$ ^google/
    ^$ ^facebook/
    ^$ ^facebook/login/token/$ [name='facebook_login_by_token']
    ^admin/
    The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

I bowed to my ignorance and went back to the allauth docs and used their default `urls` setting:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

but that also bombs with a Page Not Found and a different message:

```
    Using the URLconf defined in Members.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^accounts/
    ^admin/
    The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

I think the rest of the "allauth" install was done correctly but I am missing something.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your *view.py* file, you just need to do a little "filter" before giving away the page to see if the user is authenticated.

An example for this will be:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
         # do something if the user is authenticated, like showing a page.
    else:
        # do somthing else
```

Regrading the urls structure - just try to add /accounts/ to the url and the 404 page will show you all the end points if you are on Debug mode (DEBUG = True).
You can also find all urls for endpoints on the documentation.

Hope I understood your problem correctly :)

Comment: Hmm, are you suggesting that `allauth` needs me to create default views?  The docs don't seem to imply that but i might not be reading them correctly.

Comment: The views that you get are pretty much a demonstration - as you see they aren't really usable in a real site. you need to use the library to embed the platfom in your views :)

Comment: Ok, but my issue is that I can't seem to get to even the sample views.  All I get are page not found errors and cryptic messages about url patterns